# Remove unremoveable Office 365 fork

Tags: uninstall, webapps, microsoft-office

I've just downloaded and installed Office 365 webapp on my computer running Ubuntu 22.04.
I've followed the instructions fro here (https://www.wps.com/blog/how-to-install-and-run-microsoft-365-on-ubuntu-linux-a-comprehensive-guide/) and installed Microsoft 365 web app fork.

Sadly it doesn't run properly (my browser is not supported so the program wont run) and now when I want to remove it I simply can't. It says that there is no such program installed.

To make it even wors it put some icons in the application grid. And I can't remove them. I've tried to go to the .local/share/applications/ folder wich is empty. Tried the same with the usr/share/applications/ but there is so many items I can't find what I'm looking for and I don't know if I should remove anything from there.

If anyone could help I'd be really grateful!

Comment: According to those instructions it was installed as a [snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software)) app.  Did you run `sudo snap remove <nameofappyouinstalled>` to remove it?  You can list all installed by running `snap list` from a terminal window.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!